# How should I fix my BMP280 sensor or Arduino code to get an output?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, sensors

I recently started working on an Arduino project with which I could monitor Temperature, Humidity and Pressure. I used the DHT11 for Temperature and Humidity and the BMP280 for Pressure. I got my code to work for both of them, and for a while, the program did exactly what it was supposed to: every few seconds, it gave me an output of temperature, humidity and pressure. However, now it works for the DHT11, but when I connect the BMP280, I just get a blank output (not even the "Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!" message that was in the code if the sensor didn't begin).

My circuit diagram is [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/F5rgqUc) (sorry for the mess and because I soldered my pressure sensor backwards). My complete code is:

```
#include <dht.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

#define dht_apin A0
#define BMP_SCK  (13)
#define BMP_MISO (12)
#define BMP_MOSI (11)
#define BMP_CS   (10)

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp;

dht DHT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  if (!bmp.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!"));
    while (1);
  }

  bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,     /* Operating Mode. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,     /* Temp. oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,    /* Pressure oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,      /* Filtering. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500); /* Standby time. */
}

void loop() {
  DHT.read11(dht_apin);

  Serial.print("Humidity: " + String(DHT.humidity) + "% Temp: " + String(DHT.temperature) + "°C Pressure: " + String(bmp.readPressure()) + "Pa\n");
  
  if (DHT.humidity > 65.00) {
    Serial.print("Warning: Humidity is too high\n");
  }
  else if (DHT.humidity < 20.00) {
    Serial.print("Warning: Humidity is too low.\n");
  }

  if (DHT.temperature > 30.00) {
    Serial.print("Warning: Temperature is too high. Check for possible fires.\n");
  }
  else if (DHT.temperature < 10.00) {
    Serial.print("Warning: Temperature is too low. Check for airlock breach\n");
  }
  
  if (bmp.readPressure() < 4000.00) {
    Serial.print("Warning: Pressure is too low. Check for airlock breach.\n");
  }
  
  delay(3000);
}
```

I basically copied the BMP280 code from [this tutorial by IOT Design Pro](https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/interfacing-bmp280-with-arduino-to-read-pressure-temperature-and-altitude)

Also, to further make sure I wasn't following the tutorial wrong, I disconnected by DHT11 sensor and ran just the code from the tutorial to make sure that I hadn't copied it wrong. I took this code for my test:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>
#define BMP_SCK  (13)
#define BMP_MISO (12)
#define BMP_MOSI (11)
#define BMP_CS   (10)

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // I2C
//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS); // hardware SPI
//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS, BMP_MOSI, BMP_MISO,  BMP_SCK);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("BMP280 test"));
  if (!bmp.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!"));
    while (1);
  }
  /* Default settings from datasheet. */
  bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,     /* Operating Mode. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,     /* Temp. oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,    /* Pressure oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,      /* Filtering. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500); /* Standby time. */
}
void loop() {
    Serial.print(F("Temperature = "));
    Serial.print(bmp.readTemperature());
    Serial.println(" *C");
    Serial.print(F("Pressure = "));
    Serial.print(bmp.readPressure());
    Serial.println(" Pa");
    Serial.print(F("Approx altitude = "));
    Serial.print(bmp.readAltitude(1013.25)); /* Adjusted to local forecast! */
    Serial.println(" m");
    Serial.println();
    delay(2000);
}
```

This code gave me an output of "BMP280 test" and then nothing else. Just blank. At this point, I double-checked the tutorial which said that if you keep getting "Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!" then you should either go into the library's Adafruit_BMP280.cpp file and change line 79 to be   `_i2caddr = 0x76` or add the line `#define BMP280_ADDRESS (0x76)` to the code, the issue may be fixed. While I didn't have this error, and rather had no output, I still tried to fix it both ways with no success.

I'm like 99% sure my hardware can't be faulty because it was literally working like 2 days ago, and you can see the circuit diagram (sorry for the mess) above. I would really appreciate any help because it's for a school project and the presentation is in 2 days

Comment: We cannot remote-debug an I2C interface with hardware we don't have.

Comment: comment out setSampling to see if that's causing an issue. On an ESP8266 I have to call Wire.begin() first, not sure about Arduino though